# Ionic 7 - Capacitor geofence

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geofence

I'm trying to implement a geofence in an Ionic app.
Found [@ionic-native/geofence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/geofence), but I'm getting RxJs & Angular 7 (I'm using 16) conflicts when trying to install it.

**Ionic**: 7
**Angular**: 16
**Capacitor**: 5

```
$ npm install @ionic-native/geofence
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ejemplo-naves@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"7.8.1" from @angular-devkit/architect@0.1602.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect
npm ERR!     @angular-devkit/architect@"0.1602.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular-devkit/architect@"0.1602.0" from @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1602.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack
npm ERR!       @angular-devkit/build-webpack@"0.1602.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!         dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@angular/cli)
npm ERR!   rxjs@"7.8.1" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   10 more (@angular-devkit/build-webpack, @angular-devkit/core, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @ionic-native/geofence@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: rxjs@6.5.5
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/geofence@5.36.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/geofence
npm ERR!     @ionic-native/geofence@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/pablo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pablo/.npm/_logs/2023-08-25T13_55_16_661Z-debug-0.log
```

Tried downgrading RxJs but keep getting a lot of conflicts. Do you guys know of a workaround to this or an alternative plugin?